# loading network path in java code

Tags: java, file

I'm loading some network path in my java code. It is not taking the same format as present in the configuration file, missing one slash.

Example:

```
String path = "//abckatte.com/abc/test";
File fileobj = new File(path);
```

Whenever I saw the `fileobj` in log message it is displaying as `/abckatte.com/abc/test`. One slash is missing.

I tried with appending two more slash like.

```
String path = "////abckatte.com/abc/test";
```

then also it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps you were missing other slashes: `String path = "////abckatte.com//abc//test";`

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of **Apache Commons VFS 2**, as it provides access to several file systems. Chek it out [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html), in Local files `file://///somehost/someshare/afile.txt`.